# How to Change the Default Email Client on Mac

Tags: macos, email, email-client

I have Outlook installed on my Mac but whenever I click an email link Mail is the program that always opens.   How can I change the default email program in OSX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Apple Mail, select *Mail » Preferences…* from the menu bar, go to the *General* tab, and change the first option.

[image: Screenshot]

---

Alternatively, download and install the preference pane (for *System Preferences*) [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/), and change it there.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The first method won't work unless you set up an email account.

Comment: Indeed @LWZ, that's why I prefer to download the `RCDefaultApp` instead. Thank you for the answer @daniel-beck